# Rosserial fails to generate rosserial_msgs library

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed this tutorial to set up rosserial for Arduino:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

But once I get to the step where I generate the libraries for the Arduino with the command

```
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .
```

I get the following output at the end:

```
*** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
    hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo (missing dependency)
    rosserial_msgs
    map_msgs
    rosserial_arduino
```

The output above that doesn't tell me anything:

```
Exporting rosserial_msgs

  Messages:
    TopicInfo,Exporting std_srvs

  Services:
    Empty,

...

Exporting map_msgs

  Messages:
    OccupancyGridUpdate,PointCloud2Update,ProjectedMapInfo,ProjectedMap,

  Services:
    SetMapProjections,GetPointMapROI,ProjectedMapsInfo,Exporting tf2_msgs

  Messages:
LookupTransformActionResult,LookupTransformAction,LookupTransformActionGoal,LookupTransformFeedback,TFMessage,LookupTransformActionFeedback,TF2Error,LookupTransformGoal,LookupTransformResult,

  Services:
    FrameGraph,

...

Exporting rosserial_arduino

  Messages:
    Adc,Exporting hector_gazebo_plugins

  Services:
    SetBias,
```

I'm not immediately interested in the first and third libraries, but the second and fourth are a problem, because they make it impossible to use rosserial. How do I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196222/rosserial-fails-to-generate-rosserial_msgs-library/) by [Overv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20624/overv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-10-29**:
Please scroll up and check if there is any error message there it was attempted to create the rosserial_msgs/rosserial_arduino msgs....

**Comment by [Overv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20624/overv/) on 2014-10-29**:
@Wolf See the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by running

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

again. After that, generating libraries worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [Overv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20624/overv/) with karma: 66 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heng](https://answers.ros.org/users/21237/heng/) on 2015-03-02**:
Hey I am having the same problem. I run source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash, but I get this when I generate libraries:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ros/groovy/share/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/duration.cpp'

**Comment by [ATXCyborg](https://answers.ros.org/users/22725/atxcyborg/) on 2015-06-09**:
I had the same issue. Use the following command inside you /libraries folder to remove the ros_lib library.
`rm -rf ros_lib`
I was able to do this and then run the source command listed above but still ran into the same problem when running the make_libraries.py command from tutorials.